# Linux Website Testing Tool

Tags: linux, bash, website, web

I am looking for a tool to test a website from a Linux command line.

From the output, I need to know the response of website that user is able to login with username and password.It will help me to find out that user is logging in or not so that I will generate an email by taking output from this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `wget`?

Comment: yes but it is not useful like that I have an app whcih is running on jboss 4 so I want to login its .jsf page and logout to check that it is ok or not.

Comment: Your monitoring system should be able to do this sort of test.

Comment: do you have any idea about it? OR ANY script in any language ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly - do you need to test page or to detect when some user has login issue?

For testing, you can use `curl` and script it with your testing scenario. Something like:

1. Load index page
2. Send POST data to login and store cookies
3. Load protected page
4. Send logout request

Another option is use some monitoring tool with web checks, like zabbix (www.zabbix.com) and set testing scenario in this tool.

If you need to detect when user has problem, just parse logfiles of webserver.

Comment: Yes Ondra both of the scenario.Do you have any script or any solution which is plug and play ?

Comment: For first scenario you can use webchecks in zabbix (see http://www.zabbix.com for more info and download).

Comment: And for second one please ?

Comment: [check_http_content](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Websites,-Forms-and-Transactions/check_http_content/details) does this for nagios and icinga